# How do I globally change the precision of a piece of code in Python to debug it?

Tags: python, scipy, newton-method, numpy, precision

I am solving a system of non-linear equations using the Newton-Raphson method in Python. This involves using the `solve(Ax,b)` function (`spsolve` in my case, which is for sparse matrices) iteratively until the error or update reduces below a certain threshold. My specific problem involves calculating functions such as $x/(e^x - 1)$, which are badly calculated for small $x$ by Python, even using `np.expm1()`.

Despite these difficulties, it seems like my solution converges, because the error becomes of the order of $10^{-16}$. However, the dependent quantities, do not behave physically, and I suspect this is due to the precision of these calculations. For example, I am trying to calculate the current due to a small potential difference. When this potential difference becomes really small, this current begins to oscillate, which is wrong, because currents must be conserved.

I would like to globally increase the precision of my code, but I'm not sure if that's a useful thing to do since I am not sure whether this increased precision would be reflected in functions such as `spsolve`. I feel the same about using the [Decimal library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), which would also be quite cumbersome. Can someone give me some general advice on how to go about this or point me towards a relevant post?

Comment: Have you checked your solution when the error is larger? For example when it is in the range of $10^{-4}$ or $10^{-5}$ for example? You don't need to put the effort of calculating $\frac{x}{e^{x}-1}\Big|_{x=0}$ on Python when you know the answer as it must be 1. You can just create a function and exclude $x=0$ if that's the problem, which I doubt it. Also a quick comment about this argument "because currents must be conserved." The current is not conserved. The charge must be conserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/33486/20688), I recommended using [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) Python library for arbitrary precision.

Notice, that [since matrices in `mpmath` are implemented as dictionaries](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/matrices.html#creating-matrices):

> Only non-zero values are stored, so it is cheap to represent sparse matrices.

thus, this particular library seems like a good fit for your purpose of debugging.

I find this library (and approach in general) very useful for debugging purposes, mostly, to convince myself that my stubborn bug doesn't come from the finite precision of floating-point arithmetic. Because if it does, it is an order of magnitude more complicated problem to solve.

Note, that using an arbitrary-precision library will significantly slow down your code; therefore, if you find that your problem is resolved, you still have a huge incentive to come up with a solution using regular double precision.